# Tool to convert relevant bash script to docker-compose format

Tags: automation, bash, docker

Does anyone know of an AI tool to take a shell script made for setting up an environment in i.e. Ubuntu Server 22.04 and Dockerizing it effectively? (bonus points if it can determine when to grab alpine linux > ubuntu)

Background info:

Right now I have a shell script that installs and configures:
Apache or Nginx based on arg1
MySQL (Dynamic schema, table, users/passwords based on arg2)
Gets and installs newest LTS version of node (because for some reason Ubuntu is still shipping with 12!)*
Gets and installs Laravel, installing with jetstream, git repo, etc.

If I attempt to Dockerize with gpt-4, I'm missing communication between the application and the web server. I assume because it's a non-issue when on the same server/in the bash script, but becomes relevant in the Docker environment (separate containers).

P.S. I've manually fixed it with relative ease - but looking for a robust solution to handle this without manual corrections.

P.S.S. gpt-4 with good system/function messages and solid prompting returns surprisingly good results for a generalized LLM, but I'm looking for an application or library with access to a fine-tuned generalized model, or a model trained specifically for this task.

Comment: "looking for a robust solution to handle this without manual corrections" --> I don't think there's any AI tool fulfilling this criteria

Comment: @FliegendeWurst Fair enough, maybe I should say a specific model for dockerization that requires fewer manual corrections. Although I believe it's a valid goal to aim for, even if just by combining a general model with iterative testing until the solution is 100% through automated testing and filtering that trial and error dataset to fine tune a model, hopefully leading to fewer iterations on each test case.